# Recording a CD with piano improvisations

Tags: recording, improvisation

I have been playing piano for about 14 years and I am thinking to record a CD/album with piano improvisations.

Is this a common thing to do? These songs will not necessarily have sheet music.

I am thinking to simply stay at the piano and record music for about 2 hours and then process and eventually fix/improve the MIDI notes in some places and make a ~1 hour long album with ~14 songs, let's say.

My questions are:

- Is this a good idea at all? Or should I write the sheet music first and then record the songs?
- I is recommended to add other instruments such as bass or strings/pads to improve the background?

Comment: All these are really up to you. You want to write sheet music? Go for it. You want to add  other instruments? Go for it. There have been numerous pieces with solo piano, there have been numerous improvisational pieces

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Well, I'm asking because I'm unsure about the current trend in the field...

Comment: This is an artistic decision you have to make for yourself. We can't tell you what feels right for you. Whether it's a "trend" or not doesn't help either, since you might have the personal desire to follow the trend or to avoid following the trend. Questions and answers on this site are not really meant to work for only certain situations, so if it's the trend right now where you are working and releasing music, but it's not the trend elsewhere or won't be the trend in two years, then that's not a good fit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no point in writing out the dots before you record. Unless you need them yourself! There is a lot of recorded music out there already, that actually, the dots were written *after* the recordings had been made. Transcriptions.

There's always a recommendation to add strings/bass/drums/etc. to a lot of recordings. You could do that, and then decide whether they work better - or not. Everything recorded doesn't *have* to be on a track.

Best listen to some existing CDs with the same sort of piano music, and decide which impress most. Then use those ideas - mixes, other instruments, et al, on your own D tracks.